# Fancybox - unbinding thumbnails from launching slideshow

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Ok here's the dilemma.
Got a slider that when you click on the thumbnails the larger image appears in the div above.
Pretty straight forward.
Now I've successfully assigned a click function to the larger image so that Fancybox pop up.

```
$('#launchImg').click(function(){
    $('.room-thumbnail').fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over'
            }).trigger('click');
            return false;
});
```

The only catch is that, when clicking on the larger image, it's getting the images from the thumbnails (which aren't really thumbnails, but are just the full sized image resized) and there is already a click function assigned to them.

```
$('.room-thumbnail').click(function() {
    var img = new Image();

    $(img)
        .load(function () {
            $('#room-ajax-loader').css('display', 'none');
            $(this).hide();

            $('#room-big-image a').attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));

            $('#room-big-image a').append(img);

            $(this).fadeIn(function() {
                $('#room-big-image img:first-child').remove();
            });
        })
        .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    if (!$(this).hasClass('thumbnail-current')) {
        grayscale($('.thumbnail-current'));
    }

    $('.room-thumbnail').removeClass('thumbnail-current');
    $(this).addClass('thumbnail-current');
    $('#room-ajax-loader').css('display', 'block');
    return false;
});
```

So the problem I get is that once I've clicked on the larger image which open fancybox and everything works as palnned but after I close fancybox the thumbnails no longer change the larger image above them but launch the fancybox from the slider, which I donèt want to happen.

So basically,how I do unbind the fancybox from my thumbnails?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="slider0" class="des-row">

        <div class="des-container">
              <div class="des-container-left">
                <div id="room-big-image">
                            <a id="launchImg" title="" href="images/produits/t-shirts/fresh_tf84_kaki/fresh_tf84_kaki.jpg" >
                    <img src="images/produits/t-shirts/fresh_tf84_kaki/fresh_tf84_kaki.jpg" alt="fresh_tf84_kaki.jpg" style="width:350px; height:auto;" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>



        <div class="des-container-right">
            <div id="room-slider-first-container">

              <a id="room-slider-button-left" class="button-left-orange" href="#"></a>
              <a id="room-slider-button-right" class="button-right-orange" href="#"></a>
              <div id="room-slider-button-left-disabled" class="button-left-disabled"></div>
              <div id="room-slider-button-right-disabled" class="button-right-disabled"></div>
              <div id="room-ajax-loader"></div>
              <!-- begin room-slider-second-container -->
              <div id="room-slider-second-container"><!-- begin room-slider-slide -->
                <div id="room-slider-slide">

                   <a rel="group1" href="images/produits/t-shirts/fresh_tf84_kaki/fresh_tf84_kaki.jpg" class="room-thumbnail"><img src="images/produits/t-shirts/fresh_tf84_kaki/fresh_tf84_kaki.jpg" alt="fresh_tf84_kaki.jpg" /></a>

                   <a rel="group1" href="images/produits/t-shirts/fresh_tf84_kaki/fresh_tf84_kaki_closeup.jpg" class="room-thumbnail"><img src="images/produits/t-shirts/fresh_tf84_kaki/fresh_tf84_kaki_closeup.jpg" alt="fresh_tf84_kaki_closeup.jpg" /></a>

                 </div><!-- end room-slider-slide -->
              </div><!-- end room-slider-second-container -->
            </div><!-- end room-slider-first-container -->
        </div><!-- end des-container-right -->
    </div><!-- end des-container -->
  </div><!-- end slider0 - des-row -->
```

Thanks if youève already read this far ! 
Peace.

Comment: I think in this line `$('#room-big-image a').attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));` - `$(this)` refers to the var `img` rather than `.room-thumbnail`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes correct- `$this` - referrers to image thumbnail, which isn't really a thumbnail per se, it's just the full sized image displayed at a smaller size. On click the thumbnail / `$this` image is appended to `#room-big-image a` and then fade & removes the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If clicking on the big image is what fires fancybox, why don't you do?

```
$('#launchImg').fancybox({
 'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
 'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
 'titlePosition'     : 'over'
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it only launches fancybox for that single image. If I add the rel=[group1] to it, I get the first image twice in the fancybox slideshow which isn't what I want. I could send you the url of the text site if you like ? p.s: thanks for trying to help. Peace.

Comment: an URL would be more than useful